# How to show two divs on mouse over of the third div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement like `this(click me)` .On the button of page you will find 4 images ,on mouse over of it,they shows info. Same things i am looking for.
Below is my code But it is not working like the above given website.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#d2").hover(function()
              { 
                  $("#d3").show();
              });

               $("#maindiv").mouseout(function()
              {
                $("#d1").show(); 
                  $("#d3").hide();
              });
            });

            </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="d2" > <img width="160px" src="http://www.infosys.com/SiteCollectionImages/cloud-ecosystem-hub-mm.jpg" title=" Image of Tic tac toe small image" /></div>
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="d3" style="display: none;">
    <table width="80px" height="26px" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td width="200px"> Information/description about tic tac toe in small para. blah blah blah </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

**My problem. Div is not hiding with good animation style. And while showing div(div name= d3). My page should little scroll down. and while on mouse out of my div(div name=maindiv).
I to implement same like the above given  [link](http://www.infosys.com/pages/index.aspx).**

Comment: have a look at line 151 onward of [the javascript they're using](http://www.infosys.com/Style%20Library/JSFiles/home-slide.js), it's utilising the jquery animate functionality rather than a simple show/hide.

Comment: @kieran i tried but still i am getting problem. Can you post your solution  as a answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is what I got, it basically replicates the behaviour as they have: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMDNG/)

But please note that they have quite a complicated system of class modification going on (which you must have noticed if you have already looked at source). Mainly the trick is setting the css to be `position:absolute; bottom:-1px;`, where that bottom setting causes it to rise rather than drop as the height is modified.

Hopefully this is useful for you, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

**Try this demo please** http://jsfiddle.net/PkQm5/

You can also read here for many other effects: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects

You can also use `slideDown` and `slideUp` or `slideToggle`

Hope this fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#d2").hover(function() {
        $("#d3").show("slow");
    });

    $("#maindiv").mouseout(function() {
        $("#d1").show("slow");
        $("#d3").hide("slow");
    });
});​
```

Comment: One problem. Why my info div is not closing on mouse out from the image div also? Please check your code and mouse out from the the image div ,you will see the info div still appearing on the page.

Comment: @user1726508 `:)` lol because of you are using `mouseOut` event=> `$("#maindiv").mouseout(function() {` let me know what kind of behavior you are looking for I should be able to help you out,

Comment: same like [this link](http://www.infosys.com/pages/index.aspx) . On the button of the page you will find 4 images. On mouse over on it , they shows you info and on mouse out from the whole div the info divs disappear. I want same like that. I want just same solution.

Comment: @user1726508 i.e. do you want `mouseout` event or something else? if you want same right click and see the site code. but let me know the event you want I will make you one `:)`

Comment: Thankyou. Same like this i was searching for.

Comment: None of the solutions provided by **Tats_innit** gives expected result as  @user1726508 wanted similar to the [link](http://www.infosys.com/pages/index.aspx). I think [kieran's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392900/how-to-show-two-divs-on-mouse-over-of-the-third-div/13393291#13393291) is better.